# I'm trying to give the standard URP(universal render pipeline) shader to a mesh i made

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I'm trying to give the standard universal render pipeline shader to a mesh i made but I only know how to do it if it's the non universal render pipeline and changing the the standard to the path of the universal render pipeline Lit shader dons't work. I have been looking for a few hours for a fix and i only found `Shader.globalRenderPipeline` but that's not supported in unity 2019.3

```cs
meshObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
```

Answer (score 7):

i fixed it!!!! i found it in the unity documentation [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/upgrading-your-shaders.html) under upgrading your shader even tho that's stupid since i created the project as universal render pipeline so in my mind it should have been standard

```
meshObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"));
```